# Need to remove <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> from the xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Hi i am generating a xml by appying the xsl to a xml input. I need the output without this part `"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>"`

input--xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<CreateResponse xmlns="http://jerseytelecom.com/">
    <CreateResult>
        <ISD_XMLGateway>
            <Entity>RIM_BPS</Entity>
         </ISD_XMLGateway>
    </CreateResult>
   </CreateResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

my xsl

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:JT="http://jerseytelecom.com/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="JT">
         <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
         <xsl:template match="/">
           <xsl:element name="Entity">
            <xsl:value-of select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/JT:CreateResponse/JT:CreateResult/JT:ISD_XMLGateway/JT:Entity"/>  
            </xsl:element>
            </xsl:template>
            </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current output

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <Entity>RIM_BPS</Entity>
```

Expected Output

```
    <Entity>RIM_BPS</Entity>
```

Comment: Why? All valid XML documents must start with an XML declaration.

Comment: @SLaks, I'm guessing some 'erm not so compliant and to be frank poor implementation.

Comment: @SLaks: The XML declaration is optional in XML files however: [Tip: Always use an XML declaration](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipdecl/index.html) -- (it is not a *must* but a *should*)

Comment: Why is the encoding UTF-16 in your output? Omitting the XML declaration might require you to have it as UTF-8. Please share the related code so it's more clear which system you're using.

Comment: @SLaks and hakre - There must be an XML declaration if it's an XML 1.1 file. If the declaration is not included, the file can only be XML 1.0. http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-prolog-dtd and http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd

Comment: @hakre. If it' optional then it's prescnec or lack of it should not affect anything that processes it.

Comment: Its appropriate to exclude the declarations where transforms will be assembled later into a larger XML document.

Comment: @SLaks One reason to want to strip the <?xml> tag is if you want to output sections of a document, rather than a whole document, and combine them later.

Comment: @Matt: Then you should use APIs that output elements rather than documents, and you won't have any problems.

Comment: @SLaks it's a mistake to assume that the XML will be consumed by a compliant application, or that requester has any control over the constraints placed on him.

Answer (score 44):

Try adding the `omit-xml-declaration="yes"` attribute to your `xsl:output` tag.

It should then read like this:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
```

Answer (score 15):

Put this in your xslt

```
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
```

or

at an extreme push

```
<xsl:output method="text" />
```

should solve the symptom...

The last one could have significant consequences though depending on the processor.

Answer (score 5):

Use this XSLT to remove encoding=“UTF-8” from xml Document using XSLT.In Cdaata section You can add encoding as your will. Cheers:)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0"?>]]></xsl:text>
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

**This complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:JT="http://jerseytelecom.com/" exclude-result-prefixes="soap JT">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"
     encoding="utf-8"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <Entity>
   <xsl:value-of select=
   "soap:Envelope/soap:Body/JT:CreateResponse
              /JT:CreateResult/JT:ISD_XMLGateway/JT:Entity"/>
  </Entity>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<CreateResponse xmlns="http://jerseytelecom.com/">
    <CreateResult>
        <ISD_XMLGateway>
            <Entity>RIM_BPS</Entity>
         </ISD_XMLGateway>
    </CreateResult>
   </CreateResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<Entity>RIM_BPS</Entity>
```