# Omit xml declaration while writing to file using dataweave

Tags: xml, mule, dataweave

I need to write dataweave code for transforming csv to xml. My output xml should not contain xml declaration`('<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>')`.

dataweave code:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml 
---
parent :{
    child1:payload.input1,
    child2:payload.input2
}
```

expected output:

```
<parent>
  <child1></child1>
  <child2><child2>
</parent>
```

present output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <parent>
      <child1></child1>
      <child2></child2>
 </parent>
```

please suggest me the directive to be added in headers section. thanks

Comment: Hi @masetti, the only thing I found is to use XSLT to omit the xml declaration. Please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800746/need-to-remove-xml-version-1-0-encoding-utf-16-from-the-xml

Answer (score 4):

use

```
%output application/xml writeDeclaration=false
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a way as far as I know to ask dataweave to don't include that declaration, at the end that is a STANDARD xml.
Has @ralph-rimorin suggested you could use XSLT but for your case I would do it something a bit dirty but probably faster that is a simple string replace like the following.

```
<set-payload value="#[message.payloadAs(String).replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>','')]" doc:name="Remove xml header"/>
```

Just keep in mind that this will set your XML has string in payload and not as DOM object but this is not a problem in most of mule esb use cases.